# skew text on scroll, how to target class instead of section

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

Found [this](https://codepen.io/emgiust/pen/rdOJwQ) scrolling effect on Codepen. Is it possible to adjust the code so that I can target lines of text by class '.hometext', rather than targeting the entire section '#work' as it currently does?

```
const section = document.querySelector("#work");
let currentPixel = window.pageYOffset

//looper keeps running and keeps track of where the new pixel is
const looper = function () {
  const newPixel = window.pageYOffset;
  const diff = newPixel - currentPixel
  const speed = diff * 0.05;
  
  section.style.transform = "skewY(" + speed + "deg)"
  
  
  currentPixel = newPixel;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(looper)
}

looper();
```

Comment: Have you tried? Maybe something like `document.querySelectorAll('.hometext');` and then you might have to loop over each. But please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have only tried targeting the whole section which works but the problem is the background of the section obviously also moves and overlaps sections above/below, plus there is 1 element in the section I do not want to target. I just tried `document.querySelectorAll('.hometext');` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll => elements array
then for of elements

```
const section = document.querySelectorAll(".hometext");
let currentPixel = window.pageYOffset

//looper keeps running and keeps track of where the new pixel is
const looper = function () {
   const newPixel = window.pageYOffset;
   const diff = newPixel - currentPixel
    const speed = diff * 0.35;

    //for of elements
    for(let el of section){
        el.style.transform = "skewY(" + speed + "deg)"
    }

    currentPixel = newPixel;

    requestAnimationFrame(looper)
}

looper();
```